# Avoiding or recovering a locked-up serial port in Python

Tags: python, serial-port

I'm working on a simple serial transfer program with python 2.7 serial on win7.  On my first effort it locked up and I had to terminate it manually.  This resulted in the port being inaccessible and needing a re-boot to recover.

I'll be more careful, of course, but is there any way to be bullet-proof sure that the port gets closed?

Comment: I haven't had to deal with serial ports in a while, but on XP, if the serial port was a virtual com port attached to a USB dongle, sometimes you could recover by pulling the USB dongle out, waiting ~30 seconds, and plugging it back in. Sometimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When invoking your serial device, you might want to use timeout= argument in the invocation.
I've been in trouble with the same case, and ended to use timeout + a construction to ensure the port is closed:

```
serial = Serial(...)
try:
    # do your stuff here
finally:
    serial.close()
```

Check also the [atexit module](http://docs.python.org/library/atexit.html) in case you're halting the code in another way than control+c